# Excel Formula to Find Duplicate Value

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel file with three columns (C,D,E) and one more (F) for finding all duplicate value. How can i use excel formula to get expected result (column F).

So the above columns should look like this:

[image: Find Duplicate Value]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I see no chance to do this with a formula. You can do it with VBA or you can [highlight the duplicates with conditional formats](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html).

Comment: How about adding an extra helper column and getting this done. ??

Comment: yea, I also think there is no way to do this without adding column helper, but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `formula` in `D2` cell and this is one way to get the output.

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH($A2,$B:$B,0)*MATCH($A2,$C:$C,0)),"",$A2`)

[image]