# How is an excel formula to detect duplicate rows in the same column?

Tags: excel

I have an excel with one column. I need an Excel formula to detect and warn me duplicate rows in the same column. Can someone please give me how the excel formula should be to find duplicate rows in the same column and warn me? Also please give step-by-step procedure how to add the formula to the column B?
I searched SO and found this [Excel Formula to Find Duplicate Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832261/excel-formula-to-find-duplicate-value)
But it seems that formula is just picking unique values, and is not working for what I mentioned here. Also my column is text, not numerical.

Comment: What about conditional formatting?

Comment: I am not familiar with it. Please advise how to do it?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/740183/how-to-use-conditional-formatting-to-find-duplicate-data-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Tools - Home Menu - Conditional Formatting]

Highlight Cells Rules - Duplicate values